# how to import data to an excel template

Tags: excel

I am able to download data from SQL Server to Excel. But Excel puts them automatically in a column format. Is there a way you can customize the fields where they go to certain columns or rows that you like. So if you download the data from SQL, all the datarows in the database will be formatted in this way.

For example:

---

Record 1

---

Name | Address | Email |

---

[data] | [data] | [data]

---

Address2: [data]

---

City: [data]

---

---

Record 2

---

Name | Address | Email |

---

[data] | [data] | [data]

---

Address2: [data]

---

City: [data]

---

---

Record 3

---

Name | Address | Email |

---

[data] | [data] | [data]

---

Address2: [data]

---

City: [data]

---

and so on..

It is like a formatted template and when you download the data, it goes to the assigned column & row location in excel. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

You can use always try to use HTML tags in your SQL statement:

```
select '<table><tr><td>line 1</td></tr><tr><td>line 2</td></tr><tr><td>line 3</td></tr></table>'
```

then Save Result As HTML, open it in web browser then manually copy and paste the formatted data to excel.